# Get values from belongsTo() Laravel 5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

i'm having a bit of a problem with Laravel 5 and Eloquent. I have 3 models userInfo, tasksAssign, and taskCreated. 
The User model:

```
public function tasksAssign()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Tasks', 'fk_user_id_assign', 'id')->where('status',  2);
}
public function tasksCreated()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Tasks', 'fk_user_id_created', 'id');
}
```

The tasks model

```
public function userInfo()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    //return $this->hasOne('App\User', 'id', 'id'); The hasOne here is just me testing diffrent stuff to see if i could get it to work.
}
```

Shoulndt i be able to get the value from my User (WHERE id = id in the URL) to show up in my tasks show view with the belongsTo()? like so: `{{$tasks->userInfo->name}}` or am i totally off here?

---

Update:
Current Taskscontroller:

```
public function show($id)
    {
        $tasks = Tasks::findOrFail($id);
        $assignee = $tasks->assignee;
        return view('tasks.show')->withTasks($tasks);
    }
```

and my view `{{$tasks->assignee}}`, but its not showing anything, also i am trying to get the info of the assignee, but thanks for all the examples, they will be usefull later on.
and the Model:

```
public function assignee() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'fk_user_assign_id', 'id');
    }
```

Comment: What is the name of the column that the users ID is stored in within the tasks table?

Comment: fk_user_assign_id is the one in the tasks table

Comment: I don't know if it's a typo in your actual code, or just in the question, but in your `hasMany`, you have the fk field name as `fk_user_id_assign`, but in the `belongsTo` you have it as `fk_user_assign_id`.

Comment: That was it Thank you! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so I'm assuming your schema looks like this:

```
Schema::create('user', function($table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->timestamps();
});

Schema::create('task', function($table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('fk_user_id_assign')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('fk_user_id_assign')->references('id')->on('user');
    $table->integer('fk_user_id_created')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('fk_user_id_created')->references('id')->on('user')
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

In English, a task has a creator, and has an asignee. I'm not sure which you're trying to access with the `->userInfo()` relation, so I'll describe the way to access either.

Because you're not using the name `user_id` as the foreign key on the `task` table, you'll need to specify which foreign key you want to load users from.

```
class User extends Eloquent {
    public function createdTasks() {
        return $this->hasMany(Task::class, 'fk_user_created_id', 'id');
    }

    public function assignedTasks() {
        return $this->hasMany(Task::class, 'fk_user_assign_id', 'id');
    }
}

class Task extends Eloquent {
    public function creator() {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'fk_user_created_id', 'id');
    }

    public function assignee() {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'fk_user_assign_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

To get all tasks created by a given user, use

```
$tasksCreatedByUser = $user->createdTasks;
```

To get all tasks assigned to a given user, use

```
$tasksAssignedToUser = $user->assignedTasks;
```

To get the user a task was created by, use

```
$creator = $task->creator;
```

To get the user a task is assigned to, use

```
$assignee = $task->assignee;
```

Finally, if you want to do something like list the assignee of every task created by a user, do something like

```
$tasksCreatedByUser = $user->createdTasks;
foreach($tasksCreatedByUser as $task) {
    $assignee = $task->assignee;
    echo "Task #{$task->id} was created by user #{$user->id} and assigned to user #{$assignee->id}\n";
}
```

If the parent model has a `->hasOne()` or `->hasMany()` relation, then the child model must have a complementary `->belongsTo()` relation. In this case, the parent model is the `User` model and the child model is the `Task` model.

Comment: So i'm thinking im starting too catch up a bit here, Edited my answer, for better formating. Thanks for the help so far! Helped me understand it a bit more.

Answer (score 3):

You suppose to have a `user_id` field in your `tasks` table where `user_id` should refer to the `id` column in the `users` table, for example:

```php
// App\Task.php
public function userInfo()
{
    // Laravel'll assume 'user_id' (fk) is available in tasks table
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

Alternatively, you may explicitly tell the `local key name` using:

```php
// App\Task.php
public function userInfo()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'the_key_that_refers_to_users_table');
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried it a few times before, but I coulndt get it output to my view, Do i have to refer to it in my TasksController aswell somehow? or should i work directly with the current Controllers code
$tasks = Tasks::findOrFail($id);
return view('tasks.show')->withTasks($tasks);

Comment: Thanks for the help, there we're an error in the spelling thats why it dindt work.

Answer (score 0):

when you use `belongsTo` Laravel will assume the forgein key is 'table_id' 
and when use `haseOne` or `hasMany` Laravel will assume it 'tables_id' with `s`
then to specify your own chose you need to do this

```
public function userInfo(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'your_onw_key');
}
```